# Professor Schwartzman's Acme Canine Decoder 2000

Tags: code-golf, string

## Introduction

We -- especially the geeks among us, who tend to be fans -- all remember this old *Far Side* cartoon:

[image: Hey! Hey! Hey!]

Clearly, Professor Schwartzman could have brushed up on his programming skills just a wee bit more before he put his invention to use. But can you replicate it yourself... using as few bytes as possible?

## Input Specs

You must create a script that translates dog sounds into appropriately intonated "Hey"s. This is pure code golf; the lowest number of bytes wins.

Your input will consist of some combination of the following tokens:

- `Bark`, `Baark`, `Baaark`, `Baaaark`, ... (that is, `B*rk`  with at least 1 `a` replacing the asterisk)
- `Woof`, `Wooof`, `Woooof`, ... (`W*f` with at least **2** `o`s replacing the asterisk)
- `Grr`, `Grrr`, `Grrrr`, ..., (`G` followed by at least **2** `r`s)
- Any number of `.` (period), `!` (exclamation mark) and/or `?` (question mark) characters, which may occur anywhere in the input

Note, again, that the `Woof`-based and `Grr`-based tokens always require at least **two** `o`s and `r`s respectively; `Wof` and `Gr` are *not* valid tokens.

There is no limit on how long a token can be (e.g., how many repeated `a`s there can be in a `Bark` token); however, your decoder only needs to work correctly for input tokens with **up to 10** total `a`s, `o`s, or `r`s to pass this challenge.

## Output Specs

Faithful to Schwartzman's design, your canine decoder program must process it into output text as follows:

- `Bark`, `Woof`, and `Grr` become `Hey`;
- `Baark`, `Wooof`, and `Grrr` become `Heyy`;
- `Baaark`, `Woooof`, and `Grrrr` become `Heyyy`; etc.
- For all `Bark`-based tokens, the number of `y`s in the output `Hey`-based token must be equal to the number of `a`s;
- For all `Woof`-based tokens, the number of `y`s in the output `Hey`-based token must be **one less than** the number of `o`s;
- For all `Grr`-based tokens, the number of `y`s in the output `Hey`-based token must be **one less than** the number of `r`s;
- All punctuation (`.`, `!`, and `?`) is left unchanged.

Remember to drop one `y` from the output for `Woof`s and `Grr`s only! The input `Baaaaaaaark?`, with 8 `a`s, will become `Heyyyyyyyy?`, with a matching set of 8 `y`s. However, `Woooooooof?` becomes only `Heyyyyyyy?`, with 7 `y`s.

Again, if you can get your program to work for input tokens of unlimited size, that's great, but for purposes of this challenge, your program will only be checked to ensure that it works properly for input tokens that have no more than 10 repeated letters.

All `Bark`-, `Woof`-, and `Grr`-based tokens in your input are assumed to begin with capital letters. Therefore, there is *no need* to handle turning `Bark grrr` into `Hey heyy` or anything similar.

## Example Inputs and Outputs

1. - Input: `Bark. Bark! Bark!!`
   - Output: `Hey. Hey! Hey!!`
2. - Input: `Baaaaaark?` (six `a`s)
   - Output: `Heyyyyyy?` (six `y`s)
3. - Input: `Grrrrrrrr...` (eight `r`s)
   - Output: `Heyyyyyyy...` (**seven** `y`s)
4. - Input: `?...!`
   - Output: `?...!`
5. - Input: `Wooof Woof? Grrrr. Baaaark Grr!`
   - Output: `Heyy Hey? Heyyy. Heyyyy Hey!`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Just so you know, it is customary on this site to wait a while before accepting the shortest answer. I'd encourage you to unaccept the answer you have accepted, and wait until activity on this question dies down before accepting the shortest answer. This will also encourage more answers.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67242/8478)

Comment: Thanks for the tips regarding the acceptance process. I was actually planning to check the list of answers every few hours and, if I noticed that a better answer had come along, accept it. Sorry for anyone that I may have denied reputation to here.

Comment: @A.Mirabeau That's honourable and how it would work ideally, but some people aren't that attentive, so most answerers might assume that the winner has already been chosen. While there's nothing *wrong* with choosing a winner right away if you're planning to update it, you're likely going to get fewer answers because of it along with some complaints, so it's usually better to wait at least a week.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>24</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

*1 byte saved based on an idea in MT0's answer.*

```
\wf?k?
y
\byy
He
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XHdmP2s_CnkKXGJ5eQpIZQ&input=QmFyay4gQmFyayEgQmFyayEhCkJhYWFhYWFyaz8KR3JycnJycnJyLi4uCj8uLi4hCldvb29mIFdvb2Y_IEdycnJyLiBCYWFhYXJrIEdyciE)

#### Explanation

```
\wf?k?
y
```

This simply turns all letters into `y`, but if they are followed by an `f` or `k` we immediately replace that as well. By removing `f` and `k` we "normalise" the lengths of the words so that they now all have two more `y`s than they need.

```
\byy
He
```

This turns the first two `y` of every word into `He`, completing the transformation.

Comment: The most efficient answer so far, well done. I'm not going to accept it just yet, but I can tell you that you deserve CAT FUD.

Answer (score 10):

### Perl, <strike>51</strike> <strike>41</strike> 39 bytes

```
s/(G.|[BW]..)(\w+)/He."y"x length$2/ge
```

#### Usage

```
perl -pE 's/(G.|[BW]..)(\w+)/He."y"x length$2/ge'
```

#### Input

```
Bark. Bark! Bark!!
Baaaaaark?
Grrrrrrrr...
?...!
Wooof Woof? Grrrr. Baaaark Grr!
```

#### Output

```
Hey. Hey! Hey!!
Heyyyyyy?
Heyyyyyyy...
?...!
Heyy Hey? Heyyy. Heyyyy Hey!
```

#### How it works

Simple regexp substitution using the auto-printing `-p` adding 1 byte to the count. `/ge` executes the substitution for every pattern, and runs the replacement as code.

---

An older version used a three-way detection, but [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) noticed that I was not aggressive enough, which saved me 10 bytes.

[msh210](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1976/msh210) informed me that you don't need quotes around the string `He`, saving two bytes.

Comment: Best one so far, congrats.

Comment: @A.Mirabeau Thanks, that's quite a compliment considering I just registered here a few minutes ago!

Comment: Having three solves is motivating considering I just registered here a few hours ago.

Comment: You don't need the quotes around `He`.

Comment: @msh210 Interesting, didn't know you were allowed to omit them there!

Comment: Yeah, it's an instance of a general rule that any string that has only letters, numbers, and underscores (and doesn't start with a number) is the name of a variable whose value is itself. (Or something like that, anyway.) Thus, you can use `hello` instead of `'hello'`. (Note that it doesn't work with function names like `y` or operators like `x`.) It's a bad idea in general, of course, but useful in golfing.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 106 bytes

```
f=lambda s,a="B,He,Gr,He,Wo,He,a,y,r,y,o,y,f,,yk,".split(","):s if a==[]else f(s.replace(a[0],a[1]),a[2:])
```

**Demo**

https://repl.it/C6Rr

Comment: Although not the accepted answer, this one deserves an honorable mention for being the most byte-efficient solution that changes **only** the three necessary dog-language keywords.

Answer (score 5):

## Vimscript, <s>51</s> <s>39</s> <s>37</s> <s>33</s> <s>32</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes,

```
%s/\hk\?f\?/y/g|%s/\<yy/He/g
```

Regex credits for shaving 9 more bytes: MT0, Martin Ender, msh210

[image: asciicast]
*Demo*

Explanation:

```
                               1. Normalize words to same length & replace letters with ys 

%s                             Regex search and replace 
  /                            Regex search begin
   \hk\?f\?                    Find any letter (\h) optionally followed by k or f
           /                   Regex search end and replace start
            y                  Replace with y
             /                 Replace end
              g                Replace globally

               |               New command

                               2. Overwrite first two y of every word with He

                %s             Regex search and replace
                  /            Regex search begin
                   \<yy        Find yy at a word's beginning
                        /      Regex search end and replace start
                         He    replace with He
                           /   Replace end
                            g  Replace globally
```

Comment: I don't know Vimscript, but can you use `\<yy` instead of `\<\hy`?

Comment: @msh210 yes it's possible and I updated the solution, thanks

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) - <s>57</s> <s>55</s> <s>52</s> 51 Bytes

```
f=s=>s.replace(/\wk?f?/g,'y').replace(/\byy/g,'He')
```

Test:

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/\wk?f?/g,'y').replace(/\byy/g,'He');

[
  'Bark. Bark! Bark!!',
  'Baaaaaark?',
  'Grrrrrrrr...',
  '?...!',
  'Wooof Woof? Grrrr. Baaaark Grr!'
].forEach( s=>{console.log( f(s) );} );
```

Thanks to @MartinEnder for bytes 56 & 51 and the inspiration for some of the other shavings.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 25 bytes

A Perl copy of [Martin Ender's Retina answer](/a/83871). 24 bytes, plus 1 for `-pe` instead of `-e`.

```
s;\wf?k?;y;g;s;\byy;He;g
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>72</s> <s>66</s> 64 Bytes

```
f=
t=>t.replace(/k|f/g,'').replace(/\w/g,'y').replace(/\byy/g,'He')
```

Edit: separated `f=` and function + reduced byte count

Comment: You don't need the `f=` (as a default of PPCG), so 64 bytes works.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Great, I didn't know this

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 35 bytes

```
.cFDlR\G.^+3-\y*"He"R+)Rdc~lL-],AsJ
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.cFDlR%5CG.%5E%2B3-%5Cy%2a%22He%22R%2B%29Rdc%7ElL-%5D%2CAsJ&input=Wooof+Woof%3F+Grrrr.+Baaaark+Grr%21)

Generates Heys, Generates punctuation, zips together, joins

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>140</s> <s>135</s> 134 bytes

```
from re import*
f=lambda s:''.join('He'+'y'*len(x)+y for x,y in[(a+b+c,d)for a,b,c,d in findall('(?:Wo(o+)f|Gr(r+)|B(a+)rk)(\W+)',s)])
```

Using regex to find occurences of replacable characters.

**Edit:** Golfed 1 byte whitespace and 4 bytes on getting the values from findall result.

**Edit2:** Golfed 1 byte (Bark's "a" was not counted properly)