# Use 16 colors while writing Hey! 4 times

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, color

i.e each byte appears in a different ANSI shell colour.

## Rules

- Resetting the color of the shell after output is not required
- Must be output in STDOUT or the primary colour text output of your language.
- Must be done programmatically (iterating through each color and letter of the string induvidually) instead of just writing a fixed string to shell like the reference command.
- Must output the same as the reference command:
  `echo -e '\e[30mH\e[31me\e[32my\e[33m!\e[34mH\e[35me\e[36my\e[37m!\e[90mH\e[91me\e[92my\e[93m!\e[94mH\e[95me\e[96my\e[97m!'`
  on a recent version of bash (I am using 4.3 installed via Homebrew on OS X) i.e like this:
  [image: Reference output]
  Obviously colours will vary based on terminal colour scheme.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest bytes wins.

Comment: "Must be done programmatically (with iteration) instead of just writing a fixed string to shell like the reference command." Restrictions like this [are highly problematic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/8478) (several other answers on that post also apply). For a start it's not clear how much iteration is enough: can I have a loop with only two iterations that prints the first half and then the second half? Can I have a loop with ten iterations that prints the string on the first run and does nothing at all on the other nine?

Comment: If you're worried that printing the fixed string is always going to beat printing the output in a loop, then that usually indicates a problem of the challenge. Either, loops are going to beat fixed-output answers, in which case the restriction is unnecessary, or the fixed-output answers will be shorter in which case [the restriction seems like a very artifical patch to a fundamental problem of the challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8943/8478).

Comment: Is the example order of colors binding, or may we use any order as long as all 16 are used?

Comment: Can I write ["Heyyyyy..."?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/professor-schwartzmans-acme-canine-decoder-2000)

Answer (score 7):

## Bash, 62

```bash
h=y!He
for i in {3,9}{0..7};do printf \\e[${i}m${h:i%4:1};done
```

Must be run from an actual script file.  If you want to try it from the command line, you'll need to escape the `!`, i.e. `h=y\!He`

[Online.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdHBzOVpIWHdHRUU)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 126 bytes

```c
#define a"\x1B[%d;%dm"
#define b j,i++
i,j;main(){for(;i=30,j<2;j++)printf(a"H"a"e"a"y"a"!"a"H"a"e"a"y"a"!",b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b);}
```

*output may vary depending on your compiler, linker, operating system, and processor*

Ideone doesn't have colour output, so have a screenshot from my phone:

[image: Looks like this on my phone]

Answer (score 2):

## bash, <s>101</s> 72 bytes

29 bytes saved with a trick from @DomHastings.

```
s='y!He'
for i in {30..37} {90..97}
do
printf "\e["$i"m"${s:$i%4:1}
done
```

If I hadn´t scrambled the string, this would have been 105 (`($i+2)%4` instead of `$i%4`), just as my
**previous approach, 105 bytes**

```
function p
{
s='Hey!'
for i in {0..3}
do
let r=i+$1
printf "\e["$r"m"${s:$i:1}
done
}
p 30;p 34;p 90;p 94
```

Comment: Hooray for bash! Looks like you can use one brace expansion and negate the need for the `if` (`... for i in {30..37} {90..97} ...`) for 72!

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```
Fi4C 2:c6B 3:c81 0:c23 1:c28si20[d1CP61Pn74Pd4%;cP1+dli>P]dsPx68si60lPx
```

Of course the escape codes won't render right on TIO, but you can still [try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98t08RZwcgq2cxJwdgq2cJQwcAq2chYwRBIWhRnGhlEpxg6B5gZBuSZmwSkmKhaJwcYaqfkZNoFxKYUB1SYAdWYGeQEVPz/DwA)

First we set our input to base 15, this is solely for the sake of saving a byte. Make an array, `c`, of the code points for 'y', '!', 'H', and 'e'. We'll exploit the fact that 30 mod 4 == 90 mod 4; for both of our sets of color values, value mod 4 starts at 2, so that's where we put our 'H' in the array. From there it's just a matter of setting up a loop that runs until we hit the value stored in `i`. We have our color code on the stack, we print the necessary escape codes, print the stack value, mod 4 and print that value from the array `c`, then increment the stack. We run through this once starting from 30 w/ `i` set at 38, then once more starting from 90 w/ `i` set at 98.

Shaved off one byte by doing everything in base 15; decimal version below for slightly more clarity:

```
72 2:c101 3:c121 0:c33 1:c38si30[d27P91Pn109Pd4%;cP1+dli>P]dsPx98si90lPx
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 59 bytes

```
echo,(u:27 91),"1(16$'Hey!'),.~'m',.~,/30 90":@+/i.8
exit''
```

Save it as a script to run using J. It will print the output to stdout with the escaped colors.

Comment: Doesn't this do only one single output of the entire string?

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 78 bytes

```matlab
c=[b=[a="\x1b[30m"' a a a;'Hey!'] b];c(4,:)+=0:7;d=c;d(3,:)+=6;disp([c d](:)')
```

Usage:

If the code is in a file `hey.m`:

```
$ octave hey.m
Hey!Hey!Hey!Hey!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>38</s> 41 bytes

Now returns right result too!

```apl
∊(⍕¨∊29 89∘.+⍳8){'\e[',⍺,'m',⍵}¨16⍴'Hey!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKPdI7XS0AzI6NJ41Dv10Aogw8hSwcLyUccMPe1HvZstNKvVY1Kj1XUe9e7SUc8F0VtrD60wNHvUu0UdqFdRHWTIf7ApAA)

`16⍴'Hey!'` cyclically **r**eshape the string to length 16

`(`…`){`…`}¨` apply the below anonymous function to each letter pairing it with the corresponding element for this list as left argument:

`⍳8` 1 through 8
 `29 89∘.+` addition table with these numbers vertically and those horizontally
 `∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)
 `⍕¨` format (stringify) each

`'m',⍵` prepend an "m"
 `⍺,` prepend the left argument
 `'\e[',` prepend the string

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 81 bytes

```
print(*['\33[%sm%s'%(i,'Hey!'[i%4-2])for i in range(30,98)if not 37<i<90],sep='')
```

A full program that prints to STDOUT.

**How it works**

```
for i in range(30,98)...       For all possible colour codes i in [30,97]...
...if not 37<i<90              If i is in the desired range [30,37] or [90,97]...
'\33[%sm%s'%(i,'Hey!'[i%4-2])  ...create a string of the form
                               '\033[{colour code}m{current string character}'...
[...]                          ...and store all strings in a list X
print(*...,sep='')             Print all strings in X with no separating space
```

[Try it on CodingGround](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZ2UzdzNJOExCQjQ)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 25 bytes

```
"Hey!"4*F\mo8.D6*3+"["s_
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%22Hey%21%224%2aF%5Cmo8.D6%2a3%2B%22%5B%1B%22s_)

```
                           - o = 0
"Hey!"4*                   -   "Hey!Hey!Hey!Hey!"
        F                  -  for i in ^:
                           -   stack = [i]
         \m                -   stack.append("m")
           o               -    o += 1 
            8.D            -   stack.extend(divmod(^, 8))
               6*3+        -   stack[-1] = stack[-1]*6+3
                   "["     -   stack.append("[\x1b")
                        s  -   stack = sum(stack)
                         _ -  stack = reverse(stack)
                           - print "".join(^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 39 bytes

```
FOR I=0TO 15COLOR I?("Hey!"*4)[I];
NEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

## 4, 392 bytes

```
3.600486014960250603516045260553606546075560957610276119161318012111362072623336241062530021112402211255105115035005125205105115035015125215105115035025125225105115035035125235105115035045125205105115035055125215105115035065125225105115035075125235105115095005125205105115095015125215105115095025125225105115095035125235105115095045125205105115095055125215105115095065125225105115095075125234
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BDgMxCAN/VNmAnfL/h6XpHqpUXAAN0mhq73wZqLfBaiMEI0WjFIaUhlXGkozWMhFnsGkm32CQTAdWODLPVYRDCXw/UYizQyJE6rhxjlDgInwILxIPiYvkQ/IiNTwaHg/P@vf06OnR06OnR0@Pnh49PXr611N7fwA)

<sub>Tip: [use the `-verb`ose flag](https://tio.run/##ZY5BDgJBCARfpOkGulc@5vfHcQ9mDBcgRVKpWiufBuplsNoIwUjRKIUhpWGVcUlG6zIRe7BpJl9gkEwHrnBk7qsIhxL4fqIQe4dEiNR2Yx@hwEF4Ex4kbhIHyZvkQWp4NDwenuvf06OnR0@Pnh49PXp69PTo6V9PrbUe7w8).</sub>

Comment: Is it this language? http://esolangs.org/wiki/4

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 50 bytes

**49 bytes code + 1 for `-p`. Note that `\x1b` is a literal escape character. Utilises empty input which TIO doesn't support, so a newline is provided and not used.**

```perl
$_="Hey!"x4;s/./\x1b[@{[(30..37,90..97)[$-++]]}m$&/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbJI7VSUanCxLpYX09fOtqhOlrD2EBPz9hcxxJIWZprRqvoamvHxtbmqqjpp///z/Uvv6AkMz@v@L9uAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 41 Bytes.

```
0..15|%{Write-Host -n('Hey!'[$_%4])-f $_}
```

The day we get an alias for Write-Host is a good day.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 134 bytes

```
<script>
  var a=0;
  var c=["H","e","y","!"];
  for(;a<3;){
    var b=-1;
    for(;++b<4;){
      document.write(<b style='color:rgb(0,0,"+(a*4+b)+"'>"+c[b]);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Golfed

```
<script>a=0;c=["H","e","y","!"];for(;a++<3;){b=-1;for(;++b<4;){document.write(<b style='color:rgb(0,0,"+(a*4+b)+"'>"+c[b]);}}</script>
```